# Redundant conformance of Object to Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiview, protocols

I have this error `Redundant conformance of 'AnyView' to protocol 'Pressable'` when attempt to run the below code. Could anyone shows the error or any other way to perform the same login with protocols.

```
class AnyView: UIView, Pressable {

}

// MARK: - Pressable

protocol Pressable: UIView {

}

extension UIView: Pressable {
    // touchesBegan
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        scaleAnimation(value: 0.8)
    }
}
```

Comment: since you have inhereting from UIView which already confirms to Pressable, you're getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to get rid to the `AnyView` conformance to `Pressable`, since its superclass, `UIView` already conforms to `Pressable`.

```
class AnyView: UIView {

}

// MARK: - Pressable

protocol Pressable: UIView {

}

extension UIView: Pressable {
    // touchesBegan
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        scaleAnimation(value: 0.8)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David.. 
This removes the error but I still cannot conform my custom views to Pressable which is the main target..

Comment: @AhmedM.Hassan so you want to create a custom conformance on your specific `UIView` subclasses? Because all of your views already conform to `Pressable` due to the fact that they must all inherit from `UIView`. To override the default `UIView: Pressable` implementation of `touchesBegan`, you simply need to override that func in your custom views.

Comment: I got it.. So, I won't be able to inherit UIView, protocols won't work in this case. 
Thanks again!